# Once-only macro

Tags: common-lisp, macros

I have been learning common lisp and am a newbie, using the great book Practical Common Lisp. There is a once-only macro in the book that I spent a lot of time figuring out how it works. Even after I figured out how it works, I still have to look at it and think for a while every time I come across it.

I tried to write myself a new one, like this:

```
(defmacro my-once-only ((&rest names) &body body)
  `(let (,@ (loop for n in names collect `(,n (eval ,n))))
     ,@body))
```

I don't use any gensyms; I just use the original name. They get shadowed by the value of the form they represent and the forms are evaluated only once. For now I can't see any problems in this implementation. Does it have any problems, like potential abstraction leak?

Here is the original once-only macro:

```
(defmacro once-only ((&rest names) &body body)
  (let ((gensyms (loop for n in names collect (gensym))))
    `(let (,@(loop for g in gensyms collect `(,g (gensym))))
      `(let (,,@(loop for g in gensyms for n in names collect ``(,,g ,,n)))
        ,(let (,@(loop for n in names for g in gensyms collect `(,n ,g)))
           ,@body)))))
```

I tried to expand my own version

```
(macroexpand-1 '(my-once-only (start end)
                 `(do ((x ,start (1+ x)))
                      ((> x ,end))
                    (print x))))
```

It gives:

```
(LET ((START (EVAL START)) (END (EVAL END)))
  `(DO ((X ,START (1+ X))) ((> X ,END)) (PRINT X)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm...after hours of thinking and tweaking, I finally realised where the program goes wrong. The problem of my version of once-only is that it needs to evaluate some form at expansion time, however, at macro expansion time, the value of the form may be unknown. For example,

```
(defun hello (x)
  (doprimes (var x (+ x 10000))
    (print var)))
```

if `doprimes` is defined with my version of `once-only`, then the compiler will signal an error because `x` is unknown during macro expansion. My `once-only` will need to evaluate x to finish the expansion. That is the problem of my version...